# What makes a Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) in particular private?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpc, google-vpc

I am learning cloud computing but i am still confused in some basics. While it is accessible from the internet, what exactly makes a Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) private? Is it the VPN connection, the solution architecture, or the virtual network?

Is it necessary for it to be an on-prem solution boosted with some cloud services to be considered a VPC?

What's the difference between an application that allows some clients to access it over the internet using cURL or a browser's HTTP/HTTPS protocol in a public cloud and an application in a private cloud?

Suppose a web application is hosted in a public cloud, but it uses a private network to establish network connections between some services, such as invoking some analytical jobs. Is that part considered a private cloud?

If so, what if a third party wants to use the analytics results of my application? Is it still considered a private cloud?

I have a basic understanding of the cloud and have done some labs with scaling options, private network firewalls, and load balancers. However, the distinction between private and public clouds remains unclear to me. Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Public Cloud is a cloud computing service that is offered to everyone who wants to avail their services over the internet. While the Private Cloud is a service that is completely controlled by a single organization and not shared with others. You can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/learn/what-is-public-cloud#:%7E:text=A%20public%20cloud%20is%20an,individuals%20over%20the%20public%20internet.) for more information about public and private cloud.

You can still create a public network or private network under either Public cloud or Private cloud. For example you choose to use a public cloud which is GCP (Google Cloud Platform) . You have an option if you want your resources to be publicly accessed through the internet.

One way is the one that you mentioned and that is VPN but it is not the only way to access it. There are other options that will depend on what type of access that you need. One example is a compute engine, once compute engine is created, by default there will be an external IP address that will be assigned in your compute engine. In this way you can open a port and allow traffic access by using a firewall.

If you want your network to be private, same example from compute engine there is an option wherein you can disable assigning an external IP address in your compute engine or by the use of firewall you can close all access from outside your network (public) to remain private. For a brief explanation you can check up on this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-private-and-public-ip-addresses/) since your tagging is google cloud platform, please be informed that the shared link is not under google cloud platform documentation. The reason why I share this link with you is to explain the concept of public and private network.

Comment: Thank you Yvan for your response now i understand. someone voted down my question I don't know why! The philosophy of cloud computing when look at the first time it seems simple but when focusing in depth I got confused.without understanding basic we cannot move forward.

Answer (score 0):

A Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) is considered private because it provides a secure, isolated network environment within a public cloud infrastructure. The main factors that make a VPC private include:

1. Network Isolation:

A VPC is isolated from the public internet, and can only be accessed by authorized users via a VPN connection, a secure connection to a private network, or through a Virtual Private Network (VPN) gateway.

2. Access Control:

Access to resources within a VPC is tightly controlled through firewall rules, security groups, and network access control lists (ACLs). This allows administrators to restrict access to the VPC and its resources based on specific security requirements.

1. Encryption:

Data transmitted within a VPC can be encrypted using industry-standard encryption protocols, making it more secure and less susceptible to unauthorized access.

1. Dedicated Resources:

A VPC provides dedicated resources, such as compute, storage, and network, which are isolated from other customers' resources and less susceptible to interference from other workloads.

To summarize, the combination of network isolation, access control, encryption, and dedicated resources makes a VPC private and make it secure.